# Why Did a Batchfile Meant to Back Files Up to Startup Folder Copy All System32 Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, startup, xcopy

I use AutoHotKey a lot and like to have all my scripts running at startup with my changes so I made a batchfile to back up everything from my AutoHotKey folder into the windows startup folder and scheduled it to run daily:

```
 xcopy ".\*" "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /y
```

I placed this file in my AutoHotKey directory and when it ran it picked up itself since I forgot to use ".*.ahk" to only get the AutoHotKey files. So now I have this batch file also in my startup folder, which is pointless but harmless (so I thought).

After a couple restarts suddenly my computer went haywire at startup, opening a ton of files and starting a bunch of different programs. I got thousands of "you cannot open a .dll" errors.

I thought I had a virus and rebooted in safe mode. I remembered this script and checked my startup folder before re-installing windows and saw thousands of files in there, which I deleted.

As an experiment I restarted my computer a couple times without issue. Then I placed the batch file back in the startup folder and my computer went haywire again.

My question is, **why would it copy everything from anything besides the directory it is placed in?** Also, why does it only cause this issue on startup? I ran the file in the Startup directory normally and nothing happened.

Comment: Why don't you use the a full path for the source instead of a relative path? Would even be better if used the batch files path. `%~dp0`

Comment: That's what I'm switching to, I'm just trying to figure out why it would behave this way in the first place

Comment: Because you are running as admin. You are having problems because you don't follow good practise. Use full paths. Assume nothing.

Comment: My understanding is that you are spawning a child process at startup and it is inheriting the environment from the parent process. At startup the working directory is SYSTEM32.

Comment: Just to make you aware that, in modern Windows PC's, `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` can be represented more succinctly by `%AppData%`.

Comment: @azephyrburke, When you say, "Scheduled this to run daily", do you mean you created a Windows Scheduled Task?  If so, did you set it to run even when the user is not logged in?

Comment: @Squashman, Yes I made a Windows Scheduled Task. I only had it scheduled to run when I was logged in but it was during a time of day where I would still be logged in ( 4:00 ).

Comment: @azephyrburke, that is odd then.  If you have the scheduled task to run only when you are logged on, the working directory should be the batch file location.  If you had it set to run whether the user is logged on or not, then the working directory becomes SYSTEM32.

Comment: @Squashman, I think that's why I didn't have a problem at first. From the other comments and answers it sounds like the issue is when the script ran it picked _itself_ up and put a copy of it in the startup folder. Then the next time I restarted it ran with a working directory of SYSTEM32 and it moved everything from there into the startup folder. The scheduled task ran in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got all the good advice already in the comments above. But let me give you some more oversight...

add `pause` to the bottom of your script. Now run the script, by double clicking on it.

You will notice that `cmd.exe` have started up in its working directory, being `C:\Windows\System32` So by you doing:

```
xcopy ".\*" ...
```

You are affectively copying from the working directory `c:\windows\system32`

So instead do:

```
xcopy "C:\path\to\files\*" ....
```

You could also just `cd /d C:\path\to\files\` but either way, using full path is the best solution, meaning the script can be placed anywhere on disk... or any disk for that matter.

Additionally, as mentioned already in a comment by **Compo**, there is a preset AppData variable in all modern Windows versions, you can see this by running from cmd.exe:

```
echo %AppData%
```

So you should just be be able to run your script as:

```
xcopy "C:\path\to\files\*" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /y
```